# Insurance and Risk management

Tags: probability

(a) Manukato Ltd. produces a designer perfume called “Hint of Elegance.”  Production of the perfume involves the use of two ingredients, X1 and X2 represented by the production function given below:

```
Y   =   

Where Y =   Number of bottles of designer perfume produced.
           X1   =   Units of ingredient 1.
           X2   =   Units of ingredient 2.

Currently, the company is operating at a level where the daily usage of X1 and X2 is set at 250 units and 360 units respectively.

The price of the designer perfume and the cost of ingredients X1 and X2 are random variables.  The data below relate to the three random variables.
```

Selling price of Y (per bottle)
Probabilities

Shs.

4,000
0.15

4,500
0.35

5,000
0.20

5,500
0.30

Cost of ingredient X1
Probabilities

Shs.

1,000
0.10

1,500
0.05

2,000
0.35

2,500
0.50

Cost of ingredient X2
Probabilities

Shs.

1,500
0.20

2,000
0.25

2,500
0.15

3,000
0.40

```
Required:
(i) Calculate the daily expected profit of the company. (5 marks)
(ii)    Simulate the company’s profit for 10 days using the following random
```

numbers:
        58, 71, 96, 30, 24, 18, 46, 23, 34, 27, 85, 13, 99, 24, 44, 49,
        18, 09, 79, 49, 74, 16, 32, 23, 02, 56, 88, 87, 59, 41, 06  (8 marks)

(a) Manukato Ltd. produces a designer perfume called “Hint of Elegance.”  Production of the perfume involves the use of two ingredients, X1 and X2 represented by the production function given below:

```
Y   =   

Where Y =   Number of bottles of designer perfume produced.
           X1   =   Units of ingredient 1.
           X2   =   Units of ingredient 2.

Currently, the company is operating at a level where the daily usage of X1 and X2 is set at 250 units and 360 units respectively.

The price of the designer perfume and the cost of ingredients X1 and X2 are random variables.  The data below relate to the three random variables.
```

Selling price of Y (per bottle)
Probabilities

Shs.

4,000
0.15

4,500
0.35

5,000
0.20

5,500
0.30

Cost of ingredient X1
Probabilities

Shs.

1,000
0.10

1,500
0.05

2,000
0.35

2,500
0.50

Cost of ingredient X2
Probabilities

Shs.

1,500
0.20

2,000
0.25

2,500
0.15

3,000
0.40

```
Required:
(i) Calculate the daily expected profit of the company. (5 marks)
(ii)    Simulate the company’s profit for 10 days using the following random
```

numbers:
        58, 71, 96, 30, 24, 18, 46, 23, 34, 27, 85, 13, 99, 24, 44, 49,
        18, 09, 79, 49, 74, 16, 32, 23, 02, 56, 88, 87, 59, 41, 06  (8 marks)

(a) Manukato Ltd. produces a designer perfume called “Hint of Elegance.”  Production of the perfume involves the use of two ingredients, X1 and X2 represented by the production function given below:

```
Y   =   

Where Y =   Number of bottles of designer perfume produced.
           X1   =   Units of ingredient 1.
           X2   =   Units of ingredient 2.

Currently, the company is operating at a level where the daily usage of X1 and X2 is set at 250 units and 360 units respectively.

The price of the designer perfume and the cost of ingredients X1 and X2 are random variables.  The data below relate to the three random variables.
```

Selling price of Y (per bottle)
Probabilities

Shs.

4,000
0.15

4,500
0.35

5,000
0.20

5,500
0.30

Cost of ingredient X1
Probabilities

Shs.

1,000
0.10

1,500
0.05

2,000
0.35

2,500
0.50

Cost of ingredient X2
Probabilities

Shs.

1,500
0.20

2,000
0.25

2,500
0.15

3,000
0.40

```
Required:
(i) Calculate the daily expected profit of the company. (5 marks)
(ii)    Simulate the company’s profit for 10 days using the following random
```

numbers:
        58, 71, 96, 30, 24, 18, 46, 23, 34, 27, 85, 13, 99, 24, 44, 49,
        18, 09, 79, 49, 74, 16, 32, 23, 02, 56, 88, 87, 59, 41, 06  (8 marks)

Comment: It seems like you have repeated the same question thrice. If so please edit. Also what have you tried to solve the problem?